# Redirect printf/printk message to file

Tags: c, linux

I want to duplicate messages called via `printf`/`printk` to a file, keeping the original behavior of `printf`/`printk` the same. Environment contains multiple processes running and `printf`/`printk` functional calls called.

I want to achieve the above said, with minimal change to each binary as possible.

Comment: Use `tee` instead?

Comment: Do you really mean `printk`? Are you doing Linux kernel programming? (If so, your messages are probably going to a file in `/var/log` already.)

Comment: `printf` **or** `printk`??

Comment: I am aware of tee command and what i am looking for is, my system has N number of processes running which use printf/printk calls, i just have to duplicate the messages and send it to custom file, keeping the original behavior same. If i use tee, each binary has to be forked with pipe followed by tee & filename test | tee test.txt . Is there any alternate method, i thought off writing printf/printk wrapper and using library pre-loading over it??

Comment: Use a serial console (or telnet/ssh ?), and then via a terminal emulator program (e.g. minicom or TeraTerm) log all of the console output using the built-in recording/logging capability.

Comment: @SachinSShetty: Do you say "printf/printk" with intention to use the *same approach* both in user-space programs and kernel code? If so, you will unlikely find such *universal approach*. In Linux, kernel space and user space **differ a lot**, especially in respect with printing things and using files. Please, **concentrate on the single area** - kernel code **or** user application. And [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do it in your program, do it in the console when you run your program instead.

Then you can use the [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) program to redirect standard output to a file:

```
./your_program | tee some_file
```

That will cause the output of your program to be written to both the file *and* standard output.

Comment: Thank you!!!, but I am aware of tee command and what i am looking for is, my system has N number of processes running which use printf/printk calls, i just have to duplicate the messages and send it to custom file, keeping the original behavior same. If i use tee, each binary has to be forked with pipe followed by tee & filename test | tee test.txt . Is there any alternate method, i thought off writing printf/printk wrapper and using library pre-loading over it??